# I can't select any objects in Blender despite being on "select circle" (Blender version 4.0)

Tags: modeling, mesh, interface

I opened Blender and for some reason it suddenly just wouldn't let me select anything. Not only that; I couldn't group select. I'm like 100% sure I'm not on 3D cursor as you can see in the image attached. I'm also sure my mouse is functional too. I'd appreciate any sort of help.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried pressing "esc" and then select?

Comment: Hi. I see that you are using Select Circle. Does this from the Blender manual help? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/selecting.html#select-circle